# Change Custom Post Type slug

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm working within a child theme so I don't want to edit the file that is registering a Portfolio CPT to my site. I used a plugin to change the name from Portfolio to Stories, but the plugin doesn't give an option for the slug.

I tried using the following function:

```
function change_slug_of_post_type_portfolio() {
    register_post_type('portfolio', array('rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'stories',)));
}
add_action('init', 'change_slug_of_post_type_portfolio', 20);
```

But it removes Portfolio entirely from the WordPress admin sidebar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) filter can be used to modify post type arguments:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse247328_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse247328_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'portfolio' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'stories';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. This worked!

Comment: This worked for me after applying the additional step mentioned by @Felipe Romero: "refresh" your Permalinks by going to Settings > Permalinks and hitting Save changes.

Comment: @DaveRomsey, Can we use the same name for page slug and custom post type slug?

Comment: @NarenVerma Technically you can, but there will be permalink conflicts. I'd use unique slugs.

Comment: @DaveRomsey, Actually I have created a custom post type called "blog". Now I have also created a blog page and Yes it conflicts with the URL. What I am doing is, I have to show all the blog posts on this url https://example.com/blog and I also need a URL  for a single-page blog called https://example.com/blog/post-name

Answer (score 5):

@dave-romsey answer didn't work for me, PHP kept telling me `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /path/to/functions.php`
So I went the `array_merge` way.

Complete function you need to add to your child's theme `functions.php` file:

```
function update_portfolios_slug( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( 'portfolios' === $post_type ) {

        //$args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'presidentes';

        $my_args = array(
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'presidentes', 'with_front' => false )
        );

        return array_merge( $args, $my_args );
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'update_portfolios_slug', 10, 2 );
```

After uploading your code don't forget to "refresh" your Permalinks by going to **Settings > Permalinks** and hitting *Save changes*.

Cheers.

Comment: This got me to the finish line but one thing to note is that `array_merge` doesn't seem to merge sub arrays. When I removed the `slug` (as it was custom set by the plugin) it removed the base but also reset to its default cpt slug name. It seems it will merge the `rewrite`' into the rest of the `$args` but just replace all of `rewrite`, not merge that as well. Conclusion - set all of your `rewrite` values.

Comment: @rtpHarry this is really useful to know. I'm sure it'll help others. Thank you for your contribution!