# How to change custom post type slug

Tags: url-rewriting, slug

I'm trying to change the `portfolio` slug of my site's URL (www.website/**portfolio**/neleman-cava/) to something else, i.e `work`

I know I can do this through some plugins, but I honestly don't want to load up my website with useless plugins.

Would someone be able to help me and point out where I have to make any changes in the the **single-portfolio.php**

```
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) : the_post();

$show_title = comet_meta($post->ID, 'show_portfolio_title');
$style = (comet_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_title_bg') != '') ? 'parallax' : 'grey' ;

$project_category  = '';
$cats = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'portfolio_category');
if($cats){
  foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $project_category  .= $cat->name . ', ';
  }
  $project_category = rtrim($project_category, ', ');
}
?>

<article id="<?php echo esc_html($post->post_name); ?>" class="page-single">
  <?php if (!empty($show_title) && $show_title != 'no'): ?>
  <section class="page-title <?php echo esc_attr($style); ?>">
```

Any thoughts? 
Thanks a mil!

Comment: Did you use a plugin to create the portfolio post type?

Comment: If you're registering the post type yourself, you can change `$args['rewrite']['slug']` to `work`. If you aren't able to modify the call to `register_post_type()`, then you can filter the arguments as shown here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247328/change-custom-post-type-slug/247330#247330

Answer (score 4):

You can use `register_post_type_args` to modify slug of any custom post type.

You need to change portfolio slug to work? Then code should be like this.

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'change_slug_portfolio_to_work', 10, 2 );

function change_slug_portfolio_to_work( $args, $post_type ) {

    if ( $post_type == 'portfolio') {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'work';
    }

    return $args;
}
```